# Two string value are the same but CompareTo doesn't return 0

Tags: c#, wpf, string, character-encoding, string-comparison

I create wpf application. And some case I compare two string values. local value comes from richtextbox, and richtextbox value comes from word document. I try every solution on this [site](http://stackoverflow.com). But nothing changed. The comparision equal to false. I try replace end of file with `linkedWord.Replace((char)160, (char)32);`

**Try string.Compare**

```
String.Compare(wr.Orthography, linkedWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
```

Use Encoding to byte array and **SequanceEqual**
and more, but can not find solution.
Please help me to solve this problem.

The value comes from richtextbox:
[image]

the value comes from database:

[image]

**EDIT:**

After **Compare** method result is **-1**

Comment: why words.Any()?? You can Directly Compare strings

Comment: I need to check in database has any word to equal selected word in richtextbox

Comment: @yash because "words" is a collection and "any" is a quick way to check if "any" of the elements matches a condition before performing any further operation. Yes you could even implement your own loop, but why not since the framework offers these ready to go tools... ;-)

Comment: @Elvin a piece of code to reproduce the issue would help to help...

Comment: Hi @FarhadJabiyev. I can't look at its result, because can't access inside lambda expression method Any

Comment: What are the other properties in the collection item? There seems to be 3 Orth* properties. Are you comparing with the correct one? Also you can modify your lambda to help with the debugging to extract the variables from the item and write the to Debug etc just remember to return boolean for the Any() as the last statement.

Comment: Actually you CAN access the condition within any for every member by seting a breakpoint. Mark the text with the actual condition, right-clkick and chose "set breakpoint". Thus you can break at every iteration.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, this code works for other words more than one week.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, I edited my question

Comment: What is the second character in the strings (it looks unusual)? Can you check if `s1.Length == s2.Length` and also `s1[1] == s2[1]`

Comment: I'd try to compare problematic strings character by character to pinpoint the problem - even though they might "look" the same, it doesn't mean they're equal.

Comment: I check .Length == .Legth and they are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably that cyrillic ә(ә)  and latin  ə(ə) are different though they look same.

Check each character for equality, below you can see the difference:

```
foreach (char c in "bәse")
    Console.Write(((int)c).ToString("0000"));

Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------");

foreach (char c in "bəse")
    Console.Write(((int)c).ToString("0000"));

Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------");

Console.WriteLine(("bәse"=="bəse").ToString());
```

Output

```
0098124101150101
--------------------
0098060101150101
--------------------
False
```

[DOTNETFIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XjsIqk)

In this case you should replace the cyrillic chars with latin counterparts

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25800232/1538014) and also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075828/1538014), it seems like there is a library that can be used in this case

Comment: ow, I'm glad I could help.